# Bootstrap hidden and dropdown

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

I have two  as one for mobile view and one for web view. Originally I use a *ngIf="mobileDetect()" function (detect size) to differentiate mobile and web view. Now I would like to change using Bootstrap hidden to differentiate mobile and web view. **But when I use bootstrap hidden my dropdown in web view cannot work**

Here are the original code using *ngIf

**MOBILE VIEW**

```
<div class="m-stack__item m-stack__item--fluid m-header-head" id="m_header_nav" *ngIf="mobileDetect2()">
.......
</div>
```

**WEB VIEW**

```
<div class="m-stack__item m-stack__item--fluid m-header-head" id="m_header_nav" *ngIf="!mobileDetect2()">
  <li class="m-menu__item m-menu__item--submenu m-menu__item--rel m-menu__item--open-dropdown"
      m-menu-submenu-toggle="click" m-menu-link-redirect="1" aria-haspopup="true">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="m-menu__link m-menu__toggle">
         <span class="m-menu__link-text" i18n="header-nav|Click Here@@Click Here">
           Click here
         </span>
         <i class="m-menu__hor-arrow la la-angle-down"></i>
         <i class="m-menu__ver-arrow la la-angle-right"></i>
       </a>
      <div class="m-menu__submenu m-menu__submenu--classic m-menu__submenu--left">
        <span class="m-menu__arrow m-menu__arrow--adjust" style="left: 73px;"></span>
          <ul class="m-menu__subnav">
            <li class="m-menu__item " aria-haspopup="true">
              <a routerLink="/profile_screen" class="m-menu__link">
                <span class="m-menu__link-text" i18n="header-nav| Profile">
                  Profile
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
</div>
```

Here are the new code using bootstrap hidden

**MOBILE VIEW**

```
<div class="d-lg-none d-xl-none m-stack__item m-stack__item--fluid m-header-head" id="m_header_nav">
</div>
```

**WEB VIEW**

```
<div class="d-none d-lg-block m-stack__item m-stack__item--fluid m-header-head" id="m_header_nav">
*same dropdown code*
</div>
```

When using the bootstrap hidden code, **the dropdown menu in web view code didn't show when I click the "Click here" button.**

Comment: "But when I use bootstrap hidden my dropdown in web view cannot work" which drop down is not working, writing cases you have to write question properly, you have done the same mistake in the last line as well, no idea which dropdown you are talking about.

Comment: @vaira the dropdown code in web view. There are only one dropdown